# How to use the same SDK for Android Studio and Eclipse (MAC version)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

My Sdk is on Android studio.
I tried to select this repository in eclipse: /applications/Android Studio.app/sdk , but i haven't the effects that i hoped.
How can i do this?

Comment: What are these effects? You're going the good way king that

Comment: "Could not find the file /applications/Android Studio.app/sdk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked on my computer. You can point eclipse to use Android Studio's SDK, check your path, must be exactly:

[image: my eclipse config]

NOTE: This is applicable to Android Studio versions prior to 1.0, now the Android SDk is located outside Android Studio.app

Comment: ok my problem was that i haven't the correct Eclipse's version. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk

-OR-

1. Open android studio
2. Config > SDK Manager
3. Copy path in "**SDK Path:**" TextBox and paste in Eclipse's preferences > Android > "**SDK Location**" (Press "**Apply**")